# Как мне избежать ArrayIndexOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, исключения

При попытке преобразовать массив строк на массив чисел бросается исключение ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception. Как нужно избежать этого? Вот сам код:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/users/мсрп/documents/input.txt"));
String[] s = new String[0];
while (reader.ready()){
    s = reader.readLine().split(" ");
}
reader.close();
int[] ints = new int[0];
for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
    ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(s[i]);
}
```

Comment: `int[] ints = new int[s.length];`

Comment: @Igor спасибо! Я новичок, не думал, что все так просто!

Comment: Число в квадратных скобках - размер создаваемого массива.

Comment: new int[0] создаёт массив с длиной 0. Логично, что в таком массиве вообще нет элементов и обращение по любому индексу повлечёт исключение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если работаете в 8ой Java, то можно часть с преобразованием сделать functional-like:

```
Arrays.stream(s).map(Integer::parseInt).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Единственное, нужно будет озаботиться о том, как перевести результат в массив примитивов.